# How to style TextField in MaterialUI

Tags: reactjs, styles

I am using styled components.
I have

And this is fine expect one thing.. I want to style border-radius of that TextField
How can i do that?

```html
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';


const Input = ({label}) => {

    return (
        <div>
            <TextField style={{borderRadius: '90px'}} id="outlined-basic" label={label} variant="outlined" />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Input;
```

Comment: attach your code snippet here

Comment: Hi, I updated :)

Comment: just try to add style={{borderRadius: '10px'}}

Comment: It does not works

Comment: update your code snippet

Comment: Border-radius still the same

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const StyledTextField = withStyles({
    root: {
      '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
        '& fieldset': {
          borderRadius: `90px`,
        },
      },
    },
})(TextField);

const Input = ({label}) => {

    return (
      <div>
        <StyledTextField id="outlined-basic" label={label} variant="outlined" />
      </div>
    )
}

export default Input;
```